# Sort text fields based on numbers in access table

Tags: ms-access, datatable

I have a table that sort text as it should, but i need it different.
I know the val() function can be used, but not sure how to here. An example of what i have:

```
L125-1 Project something
L126-2 Project something else
L254-2 bla bla
L1562-1 bla
L12456-1 Project something total else
```

As you can guess, access sorts the text as:

```
L125-1 Project something
L12456-1 Project something total else
L126-2 Project something else
L1562-1 bla 
L254-2 bla bla
```

Which is unfortunate and not easy to figure out for the user.

What i have is a form where the table is directly shown and possible for users to edit, it is not a query. The field where they chose "Lxxx-x something" is limited to another table that only i can edit. (There are about 100 Lxxx-x atm, more comming).

What to do?

Best Regards and Happy Friday, Emil.

Comment: Are you positive Access sorts `L12456-1` *after* `L126-2`?

Comment: I think that's wrong, as Hans pointed out.  Can you tell us what the desired sort order of the data above would be?  That would help in determining how to get it in the desired order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Order By:

```
Val(Mid([ProjectNo], 2)), [ProjectNo]
```

given that all Projects have a leading L.

Comment: Hi Gustav. I get an invalid syntax. Also, i dont see where to put it. I have a table with 10 colums, and it is only 1 of them that are supposed to be sorted like this...

Comment: Hmm, i was too fast there. It seems like the table sorts correctly now, however, when i use it in another table it mixes up the sorting again... :S

Comment: It was - as you found out - the last part of your SQL.
As for the other table, I guess it is different, so an adjustment is needed.

Comment: I still have an issue with this one. The table is sorted correctly as described, but when i use it in another table as Lookup, and i click the drop down menu, it is sorted wrong again - And i cant find anywhere to put a sorting condition for that.....?

Comment: Don't know much about lookup fields in tables except that they cause not much but trouble. Use a form and a combobox where you are in control of sorting and filtering.

Comment: Ye, i did that. But it caused other bigger problems :(